# Is any possibility to connect one gps to other gps without internet connection

Tags: android, connection, location, tracking, android-gps

What are the ways to connect one gps system to another gps system?. If it is possible then how will be connected without using internet connection?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

GPS systems don't send data.  They receive data from GPS satellites, but they don't transmit anything.  So no, not unless the device the GPS antenna is in has some other way of connecting to another device (wifi, bluetooth, etc).  If you're asking about some specific type of GPS device (like Android phones) then there may be a way to do it, but you need to be more specific.